# jQuery not registering in second layout

Tags: yii

I have two layouts. One of the layout is not loading jQuery. 
Upon inspecting element, I see that jQuery-ui-min.js is loading right after my stylesheet but I dont see jQuery being loaded anywhere.

Here's what I have in my layout page...

```
<head>
//several stylesheets
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/dashboard/css/style_default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
//load here
<?php 
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl .'/js/jquery-1.9.0.js'); 
 ?>
</head>
```

I also tried it before stylesheets...

This layout this is not in the default view/layout/main.php. It's actually loaded in a module. Maybe this is a reason why?

Comment: Please do not post multiple questions of the same issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212422/included-jquery-but-still-shows-uncaught-referenceerror-jquery-is-not-defined

Comment: I think it's different. One is more general and this one is targeted to how yii calls it.

Answer (score 0):

`RegisterCoreScript` does not work this way 
See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerCoreScript-detail

It can only register existing core packages

You need `registerScriptFile` function and use like this

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl .'/js/jquery-1.9.0.js');
```

Alternatively you can use the jquery included with Yii like this

```
Yii::app()-.clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery')
```

**note** version included is 1.7.2

this default supported corePackages that can be called are

```
return array(
'jquery'=>array(
    'js'=>array(YII_DEBUG ? 'jquery.js' : 'jquery.min.js'),
),
'yii'=>array(
    'js'=>array('jquery.yii.js'),
    'depends'=>array('jquery'),
),
'yiitab'=>array(
    'js'=>array('jquery.yiitab.js'),
    'depends'=>array('jquery'),
),
'yiiactiveform'=>array(
    'js'=>array('jquery.yiiactiveform.js'),
    'depends'=>array('jquery'),
),
'jquery.ui'=>array(
    'js'=>array('jui/js/jquery-ui.min.js'),
    'depends'=>array('jquery'),
),
'bgiframe'=>array(
    'js'=>array('jquery.bgiframe.js'),
    'depends'=>array('jquery'),
),
'ajaxqueue'=>array(
    'js'=>array('jquery.ajaxqueue.js'),
    'depends'=>array('jquery'),
),
'autocomplete'=>array(
    'js'=>array('jquery.autocomplete.js'),
    'depends'=>array('jquery', 'bgiframe', 'ajaxqueue'),
),
'maskedinput'=>array(
    'js'=>array(YII_DEBUG ? 'jquery.maskedinput.js' : 'jquery.maskedinput.min.js'),
    'depends'=>array('jquery'),
),
'cookie'=>array(
    'js'=>array('jquery.cookie.js'),
    'depends'=>array('jquery'),
),
'treeview'=>array(
    'js'=>array('jquery.treeview.js', 'jquery.treeview.edit.js', 'jquery.treeview.async.js'),
    'depends'=>array('jquery', 'cookie'),
),
'multifile'=>array(
    'js'=>array('jquery.multifile.js'),
    'depends'=>array('jquery'),
),
'rating'=>array(
    'js'=>array('jquery.rating.js'),
    'depends'=>array('jquery', 'metadata'),
),
'metadata'=>array(
    'js'=>array('jquery.metadata.js'),
    'depends'=>array('jquery'),
),
'bbq'=>array(
    'js'=>array(YII_DEBUG ? 'jquery.ba-bbq.js' : 'jquery.ba-bbq.min.js'),
    'depends'=>array('jquery'),
),
'history'=>array(
    'js'=>array('jquery.history.js'),
    'depends'=>array('jquery'),
),
'punycode'=>array(
    'js'=>array(YII_DEBUG ? 'punycode.js' : 'punycode.min.js'),
),
```

Comment: oh thanks for the clarification between the two! That didnt work but you pointed me to the right direction, given that the default is 1.7.. So I went to config and use `scriptMap` as the path instead of `registerScriptFile`